# Bitmap three times larger in Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap, photoshop

I'm developing the splash screen for an Android application and I wanted to simply put an image designed in Photoshop as a background. The problem is that when I save the image its resolution is 1080 x 1920, but when I add it as a drawable in Android Studio, it gives me the error "Bitmap too large..." and says that the resolution is 3240 x 5760 (exactly 3 times bigger). I can't figure out why this happens, can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: "when I save the image" -- where, exactly, your project did you save the image? How are you using it? What screen density are you testing it on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawable` folder in Android actually represents `drawable-mdpi` folder.

If you put images in `drawable` folder they will be upscaled in devices with higher dpi. That is why you are getting larger image.

Put your image in `drawable-nodpi` folder to prevent automatic up or down scaling of images.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this http://nsimage.brosteins.com/ link.
Go to Upload an image and a zip file will be downloaded containing 6 drawable files.
Extract files and copy those 6 folders in : \app\src\main\res.