# Bitmap too large

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a `1080x1920px` image that I want to use as background image in my app.

On my `Galaxy S6 i`t works fine, but as I go down to a smaller screen size (S4 i.e) I receive this:

```
 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3240x5760, max=4096x4096)
```

in addition of the image not being displayed at all.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<EditText android:id="@+id/username_textfield"
          android:layout_width="270dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:hint="Username"
          android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:ellipsize="start"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
          android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/password_textfield"
          android:layout_width="270dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:hint="Password"
          android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:ellipsize="start"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
          android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"/>
```

And my MainActivity is empty except for the onCreate. 
I have read the other posts about this issue, but none has provided any real solution for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)

Comment: See RomainGuy's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428996/hw-accelerated-activity-how-to-get-opengl-texture-size-limit)

Comment: The image is scaled based on the pixel density of your device. The image is in fact too large. You can determine the max size OpenGL will allow and resize your bitmap to fit if you want it to work for all bitmaps, including those dynamically added. Regarding the link @Shark made to Romain's answer you will probably want to look at this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985858/gles10-glgetintegerv-returns-0-in-lollipop-only/27092070#comment59878380_27092070

Comment: You have image in wrong folder use drawable-nodpi instead of drawable http://stackoverflow.com/q/36113734/4267244

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That actually got it working!

Comment: Understand that the drawback of that is that Android won't perform any scaling on the image. If that works for you in this case, perfect, but think about it

Answer (score 3):

You should create drawable folder name **nodpi**. The **nodpi** apks work with all phones .

> A drawable in res/drawable-nodpi/ is valid for any screen density .if
>   there is another drawable with the same base name in a
>   density-specific directory, and the device running your app happens to
>   have that screen density, the density-specific resource will be used.
>   As a result, -nodpi becomes a fallback, to be used in cases where you
>   do not have something specific for a density.

Read **[CommonsBlog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html)**

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio you may try to add `bg` as image or vector asset